# How to worship my kuldevta when there aren't any mantras?

Tags: kula-devata

I am from Uttarakhand and my kuldevta is Golu dev. I don't live in Uttarakhand so how to worship him?
When we occasionally go to kuldevta temple in UK, pandit do a paath of durga saptashati

Comment: Do Durga saptashati. You can also ask for sacred days on which you can offer Prasad. Dedicate a place in your home to him and make sure all rituals are carried correctly and at right time.

Comment: Om Kula devataya namah is a general formula.

Comment: namaskāra mantra can be used for any devatā, the nāma (of devatā) in caturthī vibhakti must be followed by namaḥ. So, if your kuladevatā is Kṛṣṇa, the namaskāra mantra would be 'kṛṣṇāya namaḥ', if kuladevī is Durgā, then 'durgāyai namaḥ', if your kuladevatā is Sūrya, then 'sūryāya namaḥ', and so on. The praṇava should be added in beginning, only if you're dvija. Non-dvijas don't have adhikāra w.r.t praṇava.

Comment: the nāmas of the devatās can be recited via namaskāra mantras in this manner. If the devatā is sūrya, one can do his namaskāra using his many names. For e.g. 'sūryāya namaḥ', 'bhāskarāya namaḥ', 'ādityāya namaḥ', 'ravaye namaḥ'. and so on. If a devatā has some stuti (for e.g. Kanakadhārā stotram is stuti dedicated to Lakṣmī), that can also be used in pūjā in āratīs, etc. or in upāsanā. And for basic vidhi in the pūjana of your kuladdevatā, that can be asked from the arcakas (pujārīs) of the mandiras of your kuladevatā.

Comment: It should be asked from arcakas in India, not those in mlecchadeśas such as UK. The ones in mlecchadeśas are patita, and not exactly adhikārins of being arcakas.

Comment: @Bingming By UK in my question, I meant Uttarakhand not United Kingdom. I live in Delhi and when we occasionally go to Kuldevta temple in Uttarakhand, pandit do a Durga Saptashati paath. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. @Rambhakt